# Jersey2.5 - To have multiple resource path for same method

Tags: java, rest, jersey-2.0

Am using **Jersey** for **REST** application,

In my case most of the rest calls in **server1** are just act as like proxy.
for ex,

> **/rest/codes**
>
> **/rest/suppliers**
>
> **/rest/items**

All the above calls are directly connected to **server2** and sends back the responses.

A particular calls ie.**/rest/txn/update** are processed in **server1** before sending it to **server2**

So am looking for a common method which receives multiple paths for the above case.

```
@Path("rest")
public class UIALoginREST {
    @Path("codes | suppliers | items")
    public String connectServerr2(){
      //method content
    }
}
```

Please suggest an idea to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The best practices says that you if can implement a [restfull](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gijqy.html) interface you can do it.

Try to make it for better code understanding.

A possible solution for your problem is to make 3 methods with 3 different paths and all methods calls a fourth method named connectServerr2()